# modifying values in numpy array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

Let's suppose `a` and `b` are given as below:-

```
a = np.arange(5)
b = [0,1,2]
```

What I want is that for indices excluding those in `b` ,values in `a` should be equal to -1.
So in the above case
`a` will be equal to

```
a = array([0, 1, 2, -1, -1])
```

There is a method which I am aware of i.e.

```
a[list(set(a)-set(b))] = -1
```

but takes too much time, and leads to too much complexity when actually writing the code.
As always I am looking out for better methods than the above one. 
Feel free to use any tools required.
Another example (just in case):-
if

```
a = np.arange(12)
b = [3,5,6]
```

Then what I really want is 
`a = array([-1, -1, -1,  3, -1,  5,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])`
P.S. Don't worry `a` will always be of the form `np.arange(int)` and no value of `b` exceeds the length of `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if the object is to create a range of values that are either the same as their index or -1 then it might be simpler to start with all -1 and add the data you want rather than the other way around.

```
>>> a = np.full(12, -1, dtype=int)
>>> b = [3, 5, 6]
>>> a[b] = b
>>> a
array([-1, -1, -1,  3, -1,  5,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = np.arange(12)
>>> b = [3,5,6]
>>> a[~np.in1d(np.arange(len(a)), b)] = -1
>>> a
array([-1, -1, -1,  3, -1,  5,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```